# Image shrinking in a label of c# win forms

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, label

I am designing a c# .NET 4.5 win form.While inserting an image in a label, the image is behaving differently.I have two labels and i insert 2 different image in them.In the first one, i am setting image using an Image property and in the second one, i am just using the ImageList.Now the funny thing is that for the second label, its image is shrinking while for the first label its not. Why is it happening so??Please advise. Image is attached herewith for better understanding:
[image]

In the image, you can see that image of first label is showing correctly, while that of second label not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the [Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.image(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ImageList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.imagelist(v=vs.110).aspx) properties work pretty differently. While for the `Image`, it will display the image as it is, `ImageList` has a property called [ImageSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagesize(v=vs.110).aspx). This property affects the size of the stored images in the `Label` `ImageList` at compile time such that all images in the `ImageList` will have the **size** of `ImageSize` in the runtime.

Your image shrinking in when you use `ImageList` is likely caused by this. The default value of `ImageSize` is 16x16.

And you also cannot change the `ImageSize` at runtime, since it will be like replacing the list, all images will not be displayed(**!**).

So, if you display your images using `ImageList`, all your images must be of the **same size**. Or else, you have to put your images in the `Resources.resx` such that the image size will not be changed and somehow access to the images there at run time.

Comment: Oh! now i see the problem.Thanks i have corrected my imagelist size accordingly during design time.Thanks again Ian :)